# mediacodec and opencv mismatch color type

Tags: java, android, matlab, opencv, android-mediacodec

I have 2 apps, 1 I implement on **Matlab(c) using OpenCV** and the second is on **eclipse(android,java) using MediaCodec**.

I want to Decode the first frame from a same mp4 video(I need more than 1 frame, I look at the first one only for debugging, that's why I chose MediaCodec and OpenCV).

In Matlab I do this:

```
        currFrame = videoFReader.read;

        % Convert to grayscale
        %currGray = Convert_Movie_To_Gray(currFrame); % Works on a single frame as well                         
        currGray = cv.cvtColor(currFrame,'BGR2GRAY');
```

while currFrame is the `Frame[0]` and currGray is the grayscale frame.

In Eclipse I do this:

```
        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            mPixelBuf);
        mPixelBuf.rewind();

        int[] colors = mColorSwapBuf;
        mPixelBuf.asIntBuffer().get(colors);
        NativeClass.GrayIntArrayToMat(colors, mainMat.getNativeObjAddr());
```

while `GrayIntArrayToMat` is a native function that convert the frames to grayscale:

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i< out->cols * out->rows; i++)
        {
            int col = inputarray[i];
            int R,G,B;
            B = (col >> 16) & 0xff;
            G = (col >> 8) & 0xff;
            R = col & 0xff;
            inputarray[i] = (int)(((((R*0.3) + (G*0.59) + (B*0.11)))));
            res[i] = inputarray[i];
        }
```

My problem is that I don't get the same colors in both examples.
If I look at the first 10 columns of the first row, I'm getting this(grayscale frame):

```
[27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32] - in Matlab

[27, 28, 27, 29, 28, 29, 30, 31, 31, 31] - in Eclipse
```

My reference is the Matlab, so I need to get the same or at least closer frame to his frame.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with how OpenCV works, but it's possible you're seeing some loss due to the YUV<->RGB conversion.  Do the numbers you show range from 0-255?

Comment: Yes this is the range, but I didn't did a YUV<->RGB conversion.
The only thing that I do is RGB to gray.do I need to convert to\from YUV?

Comment: The output of the video decoder is YUV.  Somewhere between the decoder and the glReadPixels() call a conversion to RGB is performed.  You might get more consistent results by using `ByteBuffer` output from `MediaCodec`, but due to the use of proprietary formats that is currently not possible on a broad selection of devices.  It might be worth dumping the first N values as RGB rather than grayscale to verify that it's an issue with the decoding and not differences between matlab and C.

Comment: I believe that the problem is with the RGB colors, The grays colors are just a multiply with constants.
So is there a way to reach the right RGB color without to loss some details, and where can I see the YUV<->RGB conversion(how does it look in the ExtractMpegFramesTest.java example)?

Comment: A completely lossless translation between YUV and RGB is impossible -- the range of colors represented by each isn't the same.  If all parties are using the same conversion function, then the errors introduced should match up, but in this case you're comparing OpenCV with a device-specific hardware block.  In `ExtraMpegFramesTest` the conversion is invisible -- it might be done by the video decoder, the GPU, or a hardware block that just does scaling and format conversion.  It's also conceivable that the MPEG decoder in OpenCV is yielding different results from the `MediaCodec` decoder.

Comment: So if I need an Grayscale image what in your opinion is the best way to do it? (with low losses as possible)

Comment: What you're doing seems fine.  Without knowing exactly where the differences in color values are coming from it's hard to say what could be done differently.  You could try generating a series of gray-level test images and encoding them (see EncodeAndMuxTest) and see which implementation "wins".  BTW, if you want faster performance, you can do your grayscale conversion in the fragment shader as the frame is rendered (assuming you're using the ExtractMpegFramesTest approach) -- but that's a whole new topic area.

Comment: If you want to play with the fragment shader, replace the `gl_fragColor` assignment with two lines: `vec4 tc = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);` and `gl_FragColor.r = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;`.  Then your greyscale value will be found in the red channel.  Should be the same as extracting RGBA and doing the math yourself; this just offloads the color conversion to the GPU.  See ROSE_COLORED_GLASSES in https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/CameraCaptureActivity.java .

Comment: Thank you very much fadden, I'm in a 1 day off so I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you a lot , it's work better then before.

Comment: FWIW, I added some additional image filters to Grafika, implementing a 3x3 convolution filter in the fragment shader.  Video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg